# Is there a way to use both grid and flex box in one css style sheet

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am currently learning both html and css. In my code I used grid box as my primary method for organizing my layout. I thought it was possible to mix both grid and flex box together. When I went to implement the flex box to save from having the repeat similar code I could not get it to work as I hoped it would and ended up have to repeat code. If there is anyone who can help me understand where I went wrong. I am open to any suggestion.

I tried implementing a flex container with a primarily grid box layout. Instead of it coming in a row format as I wanted it began stack flex items on top of one another.

Below is my html code as well as my css code. The java scripts within the code do not work. I am not concerned with that at the moment.

```css
@charset "utf-8";


/*  Style sheet for WEB 110-N851 Spring 2023

    Author: John Gallagher
    Date: 04/19/2023
*/

html{
    background-color: #F26724;
}

body {  
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 98vw;
    min-width: 500px;
    
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
}

.top-split_navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 98vw;
    
    /* border: 1px solid #A7CD3A; */
}

.top-split_navbar a {
    float: left;
    
    color: #571C1E;
    
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    
    padding: 8px 16px;  
}

.top-split_navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #FF7F50;
    color: #A7CD3A;
}

.top-split_navbar a.split {
    float: right;
}

body > header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
    grid-template-areas: "img text_content";
}

.h_img {
    border-right: 1em solid rgb(87, 28, 30);
    
    grid-area: img;
    align-self: center;
}

.h_content {
    grid-area: text_content;
    
    font: bold 8.25em Trattatello;
    color: rgb(87, 28, 30);
    margin-left: 1.5em; 
    
    align-self: center;
}

main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 40vh;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(150px, 750px));
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    
    color: rgb(251, 229, 172);
    font: bold 2em Trattatello;
    text-align: center;
}

main > div::first-line {
    color: rgb(251, 229, 172);
    font: bold 5.5em Trattatello;
}

#m_img {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 300px;
    align-self: left;
}

footer {
    color: rgb(87, 28, 30);
    font: bold 2em Trattatello;
    text-align: center;
}

body > footer > a:link {
    color: rgb(251, 229, 172);
}

body > footer > a:hover {
    color: rgb(167, 205, 58);
}

div#countdown {
   width: 100%;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
   flex-flow: row nowrap;
   margin-top: 10px;

}

div#countdown div {
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   font-size: 0.5em;
   font-family: segment14, sans-serif;
   color: white;
   background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
   margin: 0px 1px;
   padding: 5px;
   color: white;
}

div#countdown div span {
   font-size: 2em;   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <!-- the Proper Taco index html file
             
             John Gallagher
             04/19/2023
             
             Version 1.0 
             
        -->
        
        <!-- Setting metadata -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="taco, mobile, food, truck, carnitas, barbacoa, carne asada,
        pollo asada, de birria, al pastor, mexican, Charlotte" />
        
        <title>the Proper Taco</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
        <!-- <link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
        <script src="script/timer.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <nav class="top-split_navbar">
            <a href="..\Project\index.html" >Home</a> &nbsp&nbsp
            <a href="..\Project\menu.html" class="split">Menu</a> &nbsp&nbsp
        </nav>
        
        <header>
            
            <div class="h_img">
                <img src="img/Logo_1.png" alt="truck logo">
            </div>
                
            <div class="h_content">
                the Proper Taco
            </div>
            
        </header>
        
        <main>
        
            <div>
                <p>Eat! From our selection of eight mouth watering traditional tacos orginating from central America.</p>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <p>Drink! We've partnered with local breweries to bring 15 select beers to compliment any taco.</p>
            </div>
            
            <h3>Countdown to Cinco de Mayo</h3>
            <div id="countdown">
               <div><span id="dLeft">58</span><br />Days</div>
               <div><span id="hLeft">10</span><br />Hrs</div>
               <div><span id="mLeft">14</span><br />Mins</div>
               <div><span id="sLeft">48</span><br />Secs</div>
            </div>
            
        </main>     
        
        <footer>
        Contact Us: <a href="mailto:thepropertaco@example.com" style="text-decoration: none">the Proper Taco</a>
        </footer>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's common for them to be used on the same page. You can use both. Lots of stuff to optimize, e.g. move all the `meta keywords` to the `<title>` for SEO and add your `meta initial scale` stuff you gotta view the page on your phone and PC both. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use `display: grid` and `display: flex` together in the same layout, but just *not on the same element*. In your case, the broken `main` section seems to be happening because you have set a "height" on the rows, which is not allowing the content to expand vertically as needed. So remove this:

```css
main {
grid-template-rows: 40vh
}
```